# Custom GA object name seems to be ignored in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-optimize

I have the code similar to the code below that is functioning fine on Chrome. On FF and IE the variant is not being displayed. If I change the GA object name back to ga, it works fine. However, to prevent collisions this is necessary. Does anyone know why this Optimize/Analytics code is not respecting this change on FF and IE?

```
<!-- Google Optimize Page hiding code -->
<style>.async-hide { opacity: 0 !important} </style>
<script>(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
  h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
  (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function()
  {i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
  })(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
  {'GTM-XXXXXXX':true});</script>
<!-- End Google Optimize Page hiding -->

<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
    Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
   [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','customName');
  customName('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  customName('require', 'GTM-XXXXXXX');
  customName('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Comment: What type of "collisions" are you talking about? Is there another parameter named "ga" in your code? @Pete, I believe OP is talking about the "customName" name used for the command queue.

Comment: The custom name is for the GA object. There are multiple GA tracking objects on the page ( I have no control over that ), so I am trying to create a custom object name. For a workaround I am going to try to use a custom namespace instead but it is very odd that FF and IE are not allowing the custom object name and I would like to find out the cause.

Answer (score 1):

The solution isn't to rename the command queue from `ga` to `customName`. You should instead provide names to your different tracking objects if that is the issue:

```
// create different named trackers
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-X', 'auto', 'customName');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto', 'customName2');

// customeName requiring GTM
ga('customName.require', 'GTM-XXXXX');

// customName send pageview
ga('customName.send', 'pageview');

// customName2 send pageview
ga('customName2.send', 'pageview');
```

(cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers)

Comment: This is the workaround that I am using. I should be able to use a [custom ga object name](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/renaming-the-ga-object) as well though. Which works fine in Chrome but not FF or IE.

Comment: Ah ok, have you tried just giving the tracker a name instead of renaming the object itself? Not all of them need renaming if you are just interested in this particular object. I'm not sure why it would not work on FF or IE.

Comment: Yes, it did fix the variant issue. I will have to wait until the tracking can be fully tested to make sure that it will be a valid workaround.